# Why I can't move this vector in the copy constructor of my custom class?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, move-constructor

```
class TestClass 
{
  public:
  TestClass(){
      cout<<"constructor"<<endl;
      p = {1,2,3};
      cout<<(unsigned int *)(this->p.data())<<endl;
  }
  TestClass(const TestClass& test):  p(std::move(test.p))
  {
      cout <<"copy constructor"<<endl;
      cout<<(unsigned int *)(this->p.data())<<endl;

  }
  TestClass(TestClass && test): p(std::move(test.p))
  {
      cout <<"move constructor"<<endl;
      cout<<(unsigned int *)(this->p.data())<<endl;
  }
  private:
      std::vector<int> p;
};


int main()
{
  TestClass t{};
  TestClass p{t};
  TestClass s{std::move(p)};
  return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```
 constructor
 0xb92bf0
 copy constructor
 0xb915b0
 move constructor
 0xb915b0
```

I am just wondering why the address below constructor is different from the one below copy constructor. From what I understand, even it is a copy constructor, but I used std::move to get a rvalue reference and vector's move constructor should be called, so they should be same object.

Comment: Moving requires a modification to the source object.

Comment: Copy constructors are for copying not moving, that's what move constructors are for. When you change the semantics like this you bork expectations of how that class's copy constructor should work.

Comment: `TestClass(const TestClass& test)` I think the `const` wont let you `move` it, if you remove the `const` then you should see what you expect but why would a `copy ctor` `move`?

Comment: Thanks!!!
After I removed const, it works as my expectation. This is just a test, not for any project. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

`std::move` just casts whatever is passed to it to an xvalue, so rvalue-references can bind to it and may steal its resources. Here:

```
TestClass(const TestClass& test):  p(std::move(test.p))
```

`std::move` will produce an expression of type `const std::vector<int> &&`, which, as you can see, has a `const` qualifier. If you check the copy- and move-constructors of `std::vector` on [[vector]](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector), you'll see that the move-constructor expects an expression of type `std::vector<T> &&`, and the copy-constructor expects a `const std::vector<T> &`:

```
vector(const vector& x);
vector(vector&&) noexcept;
```

Compare the result of `std::move(test.p)` to these two constructors. Because an rvalue-reference doesn't bind to types with `const` qualifiers (unless the rvalue-reference is `const`-qualified), then the move-constructor overload isn't a good candidate. The other candidate (copy-constructor) does accept a `const`-qualified type, and since xvalues have the same properties as rvalues:

> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category#rvalue
>
> An rvalue may be used to initialize a const lvalue reference, in which case the lifetime of the object identified by the rvalue is extended until the scope of the reference ends.

, the copy-constructor is a good candidate and is selected.